# pandas Dataframe.str.strip returns nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following a tutorial for a market basket analysis.
all works well but I want to export the data to a csv with only text and numbers.

the output of the csv looks something like this

```
,antecedents,consequents,antecedent support,consequent support,support,confidence,lift,leverage,conviction
0,frozenset({'DOLLY GIRL LUNCH BOX'}),frozenset({'SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX'}),0.22,0.28,0.21,0.95,3.41,0.148,15.84
1,frozenset({'SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX'}),frozenset({'DOLLY GIRL LUNCH BOX'}),0.28,0.22,0.21,0.75,3.41,0.15,3.12
```

It should look like this

```
antecedents,consequents,antecedent support,consequent support,support,confidence,lift,leverage,conviction
    SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX,DOLLY GIRL LUNCH BOX,0.28,0.22,0.21,0.75,3.41,0.15,3.12
    DOLLY GIRL LUNCH BOX,SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX,0.22,0.28,0.21,0.96,3.41,0.1484,15.84
```

I want to get rid of the `frozenset({})` parts of the text

Is this possible in pandas our should I deconstruct and reconstruct the dataframe with `str.strip`?

```
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].str.strip('({})')
df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].str.strip('({})')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `agg()`:

```
cols=['antecedents','consequents']
df[cols]=df[cols].astype(str).agg(lambda x:x.str.strip("frozenset({''})"),1)
```

**OR**

In 2 steps via `str.strip()`:

```
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].astype(str).str.strip("frozenset({''})")
df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].astype(str).str.strip("frozenset({''})")
```

**OR**

via `apply()`:

```
cols=['antecedents','consequents']
df[cols]=df[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.str.strip("frozenset({''})"),1)
```

Comment: I've tried both and it returns nan both times, the strange part is that if i export to json and import it again it for some reason works. but the issue there is that I don't want to export it to a json file :(

Comment: @Ultiseeker what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'antecedents'])`

Comment: that is a <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: @Ultiseeker try if it works or not...updated answer

Comment: got an Typeerror: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: @Ultiseeker try if it works or not...updated answer

Comment: Yes it works for all 3 options. I've marked it and upvoted it :)

Comment: One note on this solution, as per my recent experience, this may result in NaN being silently converted as 'nan'. Simple [workaround](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25353#issuecomment-1139686796) is to use `.astype("string")` instead of `.astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].str.replace("frozenset({''})", "")
df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].str.replace("frozenset({''})", "")
```

Comment: I've tried that. didn't work. I got ,nan instead